# Need for using EF 6 or any ORM for Datawarehouse DB with REST API?

Tags: angularjs, orm, architecture, restful-architecture

**Scenario:**
 1. Exists a Datawarehouse DB which dimensions and measures
 2. Need to develop a dashboard app with either React or Angular
 3. Intending to develop API which would interact with Datawarehouse DB which would be consumed by AngularJS

**Questions**
1. Considering the Star Schema/Snowflake scenarios in the DB would it be advisable to use ORM such as ORM Lite/EF 6/NHibernate
2. Any architectural suggestions on such implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Considering the Star Schema/Snowflake scenarios in the DB would it be advisable to use ORM such as ORM Lite/EF 6/NHibernate ?**
After various analysis considering the fact the it might be requiring to handle native queries for extracting data for various data warehouse scenarios and limitations on entity relationships finalized to use Dapper ORM

**Architecture Suggestions ?**
With my experience I have used to Plain Web API without MVC along with Dapper ORM. This comes handy for the following reasons:

1. Direct integration of data queries in the controller using SQL Queries
2. No complication in terms of additional POCO classes rather directly provide JSON Response.
3. Simple and easy to build.

Maybe over a period of time based on the scale of database growth or performance bottleneck arises this needs to be revisited.